# How can I create a new account or address with web3.js?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to interact with `geth`, and I need to create a new deposit address (and be able to control it). How can I implement this with web3.js?

Comment: Cross-linking with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47940/how-can-i-create-a-new-account-or-address-with-web3-js, which is probably a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can create a new address with `web3.js`:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/');

const privateKey = 'private key';
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);

console.log(`Account: ${account.address}`);
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const newAccount = web3.eth.accounts.create();
  console.log(`Address ${i + 1}: ${newAccount.address}`);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `Web3.eth.accounts.create()` function. It will return an account object which you'll be able to control.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html

Example:

```js
var Web3 = require("web3");

var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545'); // your geth
var account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
```

You can also use the `web3.eth.personal.newAccount()` function.
http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount

Check this blog post to help determine which is right for you.
https://medium.com/@andthentherewere0/should-i-use-web3-eth-accounts-or-web3-eth-personal-for-account-creation-15eded74d0eb

Note: This answer is for Web3.js 1.0.

Comment: How I can get the private key of the created account?

Comment: I believe you the output of web3.eth.accounts.create() should contain a private key. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create

Comment: the accounts created through `web3.eth.accounts.create()` can't be used to make the transaction as we can't use them as a sender. It gives `Error: sender account not recognized`

Comment: can they be used as receivers?

Comment: try web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account.privateKey) to solve Error: sender account not recognized